# Workaround for negative lookbehind limitation in python regexes

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a regex to identify problems in a text, but only if there is no negation within n=3 words before my phrase of interest. Here's what I have so far:

```
regex = r'''(?ix)     # case insensitive, verbose mode
\s+?
(?<!(not|no|never)){1,3}  # if this is within 3 words, you do not match, negative lookbehind
\s+?
(a|the|any|my|your)  # articles
\s+?
(issue|issues|problem|problems) # words of interest
'''
```

Should match:

```
matches = [
"a problem",
"the issue",
"any of the issues",
"not even close to being your issue",
]
```

Should not match:

```
non_matches = [
  "not a problem",
  "never your problem",
  "not the issue",
  "not overwhelmingly your issue",
  "not too close your issue"
]
```

If I run without the negative look-behind:

```
regex2 = r'''(?ix)  # case insensitive, verbose
(a|the|any|my|your)    # articles
\s+?
(issue|issues|problem|problems) # words of interest
'''
```

I get the correct positive matches.

```
>>> for p in matches:
...   print(re.findall(regex2, p))
[('a', 'problem')]
[('the', 'issue')]
[('the', 'issue')]
[('your', 'issue')]
```

But if I include the negative lookahead I need in order to correctly exclude the negative matches, I get:

```
re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

I understand this is just a limitation of the python regex engine, but what is the appropriate workaround commonly used in this situation?  Is there a simple way I can OR together 0,1,2,3 patterns to handle it?  Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install PyPi regex module and forget about the lookbehind pattern limitations.

```
import regex
rx = r'''(?ix)     # case insensitive, verbose mode
(?<!\b(?:not|no|never)(?:\s+\S+){0,2}\s+)  # if this is within 3 words, you do not match, negative lookbehind
(a|the|any|my|your)  # articles
\s+
(issue|issues|problem|problems)\b # words of interest
'''
```

and then

```py
for p in matches:
    print(regex.findall(rx, p))

# [('a', 'problem')]
# [('the', 'issue')]
# [('the', 'issues')]
# [('your', 'issue')]

for p in non_matches:
    print(regex.findall(rx, p))

# []
# []
# []
# []
# []
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##hVJBboMwELz7Fdv0EFBQVTW3qFUe0WOpKgNLsGq8yHYSUN230zUlKTkVIbDHOzuzA93gGzLbcVRtR9aDxQP2wvbwAna9Xid71acQr3sopUNQxqFxyqsTZnBCWxCDLVUokv3zXV4k@50hHwwFg3yc8j53m/x1k349Zk/fvE5jL1WDb5QDvs@KVwa2cCZbuQwGOkJFwF2glb5sMjB4kFEQNNFngVxdiUQG32CQZgjtEJhjp77SelVqdIKFRKKcO2KYni50lgqN7eXt0rxgwiQKVPNgHi06L3hqMQmj4xDexErCTFllYsWiMDWMG1aP1CvmIhiN8@gGSh2z8QQFKnOIc9kr9V0YMh9LGYCJuRSLUAzxl3qLc@nSygwRV58b1C0L6uFW8sIimp0tTtlPTSzBKcBsaifiV@8s55JMP8VDzblLrRPbZ9ClqfijLGb5lzaOPw).

NOTES:

- `(?<!\b(?:not|no|never)(?:\s+\S+){0,2}\s+)` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if the current location is immediately preceded with a whole word `not`, `no` or `never` and then has zero, one or two repetitions of one or more whitespaces followed with one or more non-whitespaces and then one or more whitespaces. So, all in all the negative words can appear up to 3 words far from the words of interest.
- Use non-capturing groups, `(?:...)`, around the pattern parts you do not need to extract, as `re.findall` and `regex.findall` always return only captures if capturing groups are defined in the pattern. Else, you would need a `.finditer` method.
- Pay attention to `(issue|issues|problem|problems)\b`: the word boundary at the end makes the regex engine match these words as whole words, and if thereis `issues`, it will return this word in full. If you do not use `\b` and you still want to get `[('the', 'issues')]` as the result of the third `matches` string you will need to put `issues` alternative before the `issue` one as the first alternative matched "wins" and the rest is not tried.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this *work-around* approach in Python in the absence of a dynamic length lookbehind support:

```sh
regex = r'''(?ixm)
^
(?!.*
   \b(?:not?|never)\s+
   (?:\w+\s+){0,2}
   (?:a|the|any|my|your)\s+
   (?:issues?|problems?)
)
.*\b(a|the|any|my|your)
\s+
(issues?|problems?)
'''
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SJu98N/2)

Here we are using a negative lookahead at the start of the regex to fail the match if we have *non-allowed* pattern present in the input.

```sh
(?!.*
   \b(?:not?|never)\s+
   (?:\w+\s+){0,2}
   (?:a|the|any|my|your)\s+
   (?:issues?|problems?)
)
```

This will fail a match when we have `no` or `not` or `never` within 1 to 3 words of an article followed by word of your interest.

Comment: This is a great solution -- I was thinking up something hideously more complex.

Comment: A difference with the regex-based solution above is that "a problem but maybe not really a problem" is matched by the regex-based solution but not matched with this work-around solution.